# Add commas to numeric strings in Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Add commas to numbers in Unix, need to change `1234567` as `1,234,567`

Is it possible in `sed` or `awk`? If so please give some sample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ LC_NUMERIC=en_US

$ printf "%'.f" 1234567
1,234,567
```

Courtesy of [jim mcnamara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348312): Locale determines what happens with the thousands separator.

```
$ export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
$ printf "%'f\n" 1234567.777
1,234,567.777000

$ export LC_NUMERIC=C
$ printf "%'f\n" 1234567.777
1234567.777000
```

This last one has no commas. Your result had no commas. Do you see why now?  Locale LC_NUMERIC setting is your answer. The C locale does not have a thousands separator. I'm guessing your locale does not either.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, for some reason. What am I doing wrong?
    $ export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
    $ printf "%'f\n" 1234567.777
    1234567.777000
For reference, this is bash 4.3.11(1) under Kubuntu 14.04. ** EDIT ** It works if I set LC_ALL to en_US.UTF-8, but LC_NUMERIC appears to be ignored, even though the printf() documentation says LC_NUMERIC is what's used.

Comment: Why there is single quot here before f `"%'f\n"` if I put it like this will give me error ,,, this is command I use it for `ps aux|grep "$1" | awk '{count+=$6}END{ printf  "%f\n",count }'` still not thousand comma separated .

Answer (score 0):

Ive used this once :

```
echo "1234567890" | \
sed -e ': L
s/\([0-9]\{1,19\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/
t L'
```

should work

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/format-numbers-using-bash-672031/#post4269148